# Как с помощью ckeditor 5 вывести из БД в textarea отформатированный текст?

Tags: ckeditor, textarea

Я пытаюсь выводить из базы данных текст с форматированными html тэгами и стилями, но чтобы html и css не был текстом, а применялся. Вывести я пытаюсь в  Ckeditor 5. Вот что получается если использовать только **echo json_encode($cust)**

```
<blockquote><ul><li><span style="background-color:hsl(270, 75%, 60%);">astra</span></li><li><span style="background-color:hsl(270, 75%, 60%);">master</span></li><li><span style="background-color:hsl(270, 75%, 60%);">lomaster</span></li></ul></blockquote>
```

Если вывести через декодирование **echo html_entity_decode(json_encode($cust))**,
то textarea вообще ничего не выводит, но самое главное если есть только простенькие тэги типа **p, h1**, то они форматируются и выводятся! В textarea Ckeditor 5 мне нужно отредактировать данные из БД и отправить обратно. Всё это я делаю через аякс. Если не декодировать, то каждый раз когда я отправляю в БД отредактированные данные Ckeditor их шифрует и во второй проход получается так:

```
<p>&lt;blockquote&gt;&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;span style="background-color:hsl(270, 75%, 60%);"&gt;astra12&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;span style="background-color:hsl(270, 75%, 60%);"&gt;master12&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;span style="background-color:hsl(270, 75%, 60%);"&gt;lomaster12&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;&lt;/blockquote&gt;</p>
```

textarea неспособна форматировать html. Это должен делать редактор, а как он делает я не понимаю. В инструкциях из того, что понял ничего про это. Может кто-нибудь знает об этом что-нибудь?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для вывода отформатированного текста с HTML и CSS в Ckeditor 5 из базы данных вам нужно использовать метод setData() объекта editor, чтобы установить значение редактора. Вы можете передать отформатированный текст в этот метод в качестве параметра.

Пример кода на PHP:

```
// Получаем отформатированный текст из базы данных
$formattedText = '<blockquote><ul><li><span style="background-color:hsl(270, 75%, 60%);">astra</span></li><li><span style="background-color:hsl(270, 75%, 60%);">master</span></li><li><span style="background-color:hsl(270, 75%, 60%);">lomaster</span></li></ul></blockquote>';

// Устанавливаем значение редактора
$editorValue = htmlspecialchars_decode($formattedText);
$editor->setData($editorValue);
```

В этом примере мы используем функцию htmlspecialchars_decode() для декодирования HTML-кода в отформатированном тексте, чтобы он отображался в Ckeditor 5 как HTML и CSS.

Если вы хотите отправить отредактированный текст обратно в базу данных, вам нужно использовать метод getData() объекта editor, чтобы получить значение редактора в виде отформатированного текста.

Пример кода на JavaScript:

```
// Получаем значение редактора
var editedValue = editor.getData();

// Отправляем отредактированный текст на сервер
$.ajax({
    url: 'save-edited-text.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {editedText: editedValue},
    success: function(response) {
        // Обрабатываем ответ сервера
    }
});
```

В этом примере мы используем метод getData() объекта editor для получения отредактированного текста в виде отформатированного HTML и CSS. Затем мы отправляем его на сервер с помощью jQuery.ajax() и сохраняем его в базе данных.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Ваш ответ показывает обработку ckeditor через аякс с начала до конца. Это не совсем ответ на мой вопрос, но он натолкнул меня на мысль проверить свой обработчик с самого начала и выяснилось, что у меня стоял ещё один **htmlspecialchars**, который и мешал декодированию. Я избавился от него и всё заработало.